# Access to fetch at <URL> from origin <localhost> has been blocked by CORS policy for an idle chrome session

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am getting a weird error after a Chrome tab/session has been idle on my React app. I am using Apollo GraphQL Client.

I haven't timed it exactly, but after sitting on a page for more than 30 minutes or so, if I was to click to switch to a route, and there would be an attempt to fetch some data from the servier, I would get this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.xxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com/nonprod/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

After I refresh the page, it resumes working fine.

Below is the entirety of my ApolloWrapper:

```
const uploadLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT_URL,
});

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${
          typeof locations === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(locations) : locations
        }, Path: ${path}`,
      ),
    );

  if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});

const ApolloWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const { session, logout, refreshSession } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const retryLink = new RetryLink({
    delay: {
      initial: 0,
    },
    attempts: {
      max: 2,
      retryIf: async (err) => {
        // when unauthorize response from server, refresh id token
        if ([401, 403].includes(err.statusCode)) {
          try {
            await refreshSession();
          } catch (error) {
            logout();
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        }
        return true;
      },
    },
  });

  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
    const token = session.idToken.jwtToken;
    // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them

    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        Authorization: token ? `${token}` : '',
      },
    };
  });

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: errorLink.concat(retryLink).concat(authLink).concat(uploadLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
};

export default ApolloWrapper;
```

I thought that it may be my token expiring, but I am refreshing it, so I don't think anything strange is happening there.

Looking into Chrome DevTools, it isn't giving me an HTTP response code of any sort, and I'm not even hitting the backend, as my CloudWatch logs don't reveal anything.

What could be causing this?